# problems of testing number of permitted continuous assignment on reg based on SV LRM

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I wanted to figure out how many number of continuous assignment held in one wire/reg is legal based on SV LRM.

I looked over verilog and SV LRM and it states the below.

`"Continuous assignments shall drive values onto nets or variables" - SV LRM 10.3`
This means continous assignment on reg is allowed unlike verilog.
(Continuous assignments shall drive values onto nets - verilog LRM 6.1)

`"The continuous assignment statement shall place a continuous assignment on a net or variable data type." - SV LRM 10.3.2`
This means number of continuous assignment on wire/reg is limited to 1.

Compromising above two,
***I concluded wire and reg can have only one continuous assignment for each in SV.***

Then I wanted to check through compilation in Modelsim.

```
> testing multi assignments in reg
module test_1;
    reg a;
    assign a = 1;
    assign a = 0;
    
endmodule
```

> Console: " 'a' is driven by more than one continuous assignment "
> So, this compilation seeked out multidriving on reg very well. Nothing to complain.

```
>testing multi assignments on wire
module test_2;
    wire a;
    assign a = 1;
    assign a = 0;
    
endmodule
```

> Console: " Compile of SVtest.sv was successful "
> I expected the result to give out error.
> ***However, this compilation didn't sort out error of multi drivers on wire.***
> ***Which means UVA allows double drive on wire quite different than I expected.***

***Question abstract:***
***Is my interpretation of SV LRM(only one continuous assignment is permitted on a wire/reg) wrong? Or Is it just simulator not strictly reflecting SV LRM?***

***Moreover, is interpretation that I made earlier(In verilog, continuous assignment is permitted only once on wire but not allowed on reg) also wrong?(based on  "Continuous assignments shall drive values onto nets - verilog LRM 6.1")***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A net/wire can have multiple *continuous* assignments, but no *procedural* assignments. A variable can have multiple *procedural* assignments, OR a single continuous assignment. See https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2013/05/03/wire-vs-reg/

Comment: Thank you for kind advice. But still there is something that makes me wonder. I empirically know that multiple continuous assignment on wire/net would not give error in compiler stage in SV.(It may work based on result resolution or would give X like article you kindly posted.) However, SV LRM 10.3.2 states "The continuous assignment statement shall place a continuous assignment on a net or variable data type". So, I thought LRM does not allow multiple continuous drivers in wire.  These are quite conflicting together.

Comment: It is true that _each_ continuous assignment statement places a _single continuous assignment_ on a net. But there is nothing in what you quoted that restricts to only having a single statement. Continuous assignments have many forms in addition to an explicit statement. Port connections are implicit continuous assignments.

Comment: I think I grasp the idea. The quote just meaning single assignment statement placing single assignment, not restricting number of statement that shall be placed on that.(And if there are multiple number, it will pick one based on result resolution as article.) Thank you really much for your help.